# Rails ActiveAdmin のログインができなくなった

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

Ruby on Rails で ActiveAdmin を導入し、管理者ユーザーの登録やダッシュボードの生成など行いました。
少し時間を空けて ActiveAdmin にログインしようと思ったら、ログインができなくなりました。
初期の admin@example.com, password は削除して、自分の設定していました。
自分で設定したアドレスやパスワードに間違いはありません。

パスワードリセットの画面に飛び、メールアドレスを入力するとアドレスはない　と弾かれてしまいます。
何か解決方法はありますでしょうか？
もしくは、再設定する方法などありますでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/77923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、DBのadmin_usersテーブル（デフォルトではadmin_usersですが、もし変更していたら読み替えてください）に管理者のレコードが登録されているはずですので、登録されているemailを確認してみてください。
そのemailでパスワードの再設定を行うとパスワード変更できると思います。

admin_usersが空だったりした場合は、seedなどで管理者データを作り直してログインすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました！無事解決しました！